# Firebase firebase.app().options returns Object {}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am setting up firebase phone auth correctly (I think), but it is throwing an error, why does this happen?
the code for this is:

```
import { FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal } from 'expo-firebase-recaptcha';
import firebase from '../database/firebase';
interface props {}
const PhoneAuth = (props: props) => {
  const reCaptchaRef = React.useRef<any>(null);
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = React.useState<string>('');
  const [verificationId, setVerificationId] = React.useState<string>('');
  const [verificationCode, setVerificationCode] = React.useState<string>('');
  const firebaseConfig = firebase.apps.length
    ? firebase.app().options
    : undefined;
  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal
        ref={reCaptchaRef}
        firebaseConfig={firebaseConfig}
        attemptInvisibleVerification={true}
      />
    
    ...
```

if I `console.log(firebaseConfig);` the response is `Object {}` not containing my app settings.

and yes, I did imported firebase and initialized it correctly.

[image]

Comment: How does this file look like? `import firebase from '../database/firebase';`